# How to close the dialog on clicking a button using TypeScript and React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to close the dialog by clicking a button using TypeScript and React.

**What I am trying to do:**

On [click me] button click, `isDialogOpen` state is set to `true` and dialog shows up if `isDialogOpen` is `true`.

This dialog should close if this [click me] button is clicked or user clicks anywhere outside the dialog.

Below is my code:

```
function Parent() {
    const [isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen] = React.useState(false);
    return (
        <button onClick={() => setIsDialogOpen(!isDialogOpen)}> click me </button> //on clicking this 
        //button should open the dialog. if dialog open 
        //and clicking this button again should close the dialog
        {isDialogOpen && 
            <Dialog setIsDialogOpen={setIsDialogOpen}/>
        }
    );
}


function Dialog({setIsDialogOpen}: Props) {
    const dialogRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const handleClickOutsideDialog = (event: any) => {
            if (
                dialogRef && dialogRef.current && 
                !dialogRef.current.contains(event.target)
            ) {
                setIsDialogOpen(false);
            }
        };
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutsideDialog);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutsideDialog);
        };
    }, [setIsDialogOpen, dialogRef]);
    
    return (
        <Wrapper ref={dialogRef}>
            <Title> title </Title>
            <Description> some big description </Description>
        </Wrapper>
    );
}
```

It works fine. But the problem is once the dialog is opened then clicking the click me button....the dialog disappears and immediately opens.

I am expecting the dialog to close when the user clicks click me button if the dialog is opened before.

I don't know where the problem is. Could someone help me with this? Thanks.

**EDIT**

below is what i have tried again adding a ref to button click me. and passing it to dialog component to check in useeffect method.

```
function Parent() {
    const [isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const buttonRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const handleClick = () => {
        if (!isDialogOpen) {
            setIsDialogOpen(true);
        }
    };
    return (
        <button onClick={handelClick}> click me </button> //on clicking this 
        //button should open the dialog. if dialog open 
        //and clicking this button again should close the dialog
        {isDialogOpen && 
            <Dialog setIsDialogOpen={setIsDialogOpen} buttonRef={buttonRef}/>
        }
    );
}


function Dialog({setIsDialogOpen, buttonRef}: Props) {
    const dialogRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const handleClickOutsideDialog = (event: any) => {
            if (
                dialogRef && dialogRef.current && 
                !dialogRef.current.contains(event.target) && buttonRef && 
            buttonRef.current && !buttonRef.current.contains(event.target)
            ) {
                setIsDialogOpen(false);
            }
        };
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutsideDialog);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutsideDialog);
        };
    }, [setIsDialogOpen, dialogRef]);
    
    return (
        <Wrapper ref={dialogRef}>
            <Title> title </Title>
            <Description> some big description </Description>
        </Wrapper>
    );
}
```

but this keep the dialog open even though user clicks the click me button. clicking outside the dialog will close it.

Comment: What is the "click me button dialog"? Do you mean "click me" button disappears?

Comment: nope. clicking the click me button makes the dialog disappear and reopen again.

Comment: Its difficult to assess without a live example but try changing your button click handler to `() => setIsDialogOpen((open) => !open)`

Comment: thanks but it is the same. could it be because of the useeffect in the dialog component. there i am checking if the click was outside dialog. so if user clicks on the click me button it is counted as clicked outside dialog and isDialogOpen is set to false and then again set to true since click me button onclick method gets called???? how can i change that

Comment: Can you upload your Wrapper component here?

Comment: @someuser2491 Why not disable the "Click me" button if the dialog is open?

Comment: hmm but thats not as per the design.

Comment: @Mithhu i have added wrapper component. it contains a title and description text.

Comment: You have a race condition. For appearance sake, you could use `onClickClickMe = () => { if (!isDialogOpen) setIsDialogOpen(true) };` Then set `onClick={onClickClickMe}'

Comment: thanks. could you please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continued from comments.

Try setIsDialogOpen((open) => !open)

---

You have a race condition. For appearance sake, you could use `const onClickClickMe = () => { if (!isDialogOpen) setIsDialogOpen(true) };` Then set `onClick={onClickClickMe}`

Comment: tested it. and is the same. the problem is the code inside useeffect executes first setting isDialogOpen to false. then this onClickClickMe executes and set isDialogOpen to true.

Comment: @someuser2491 could you post a small sample on codesandbox?

Comment: i have edited my question on what i have tried adding a ref to click me button.

Comment: @someuser2491 When setDialogOpen is set to false by handleClickOutsideDialog, it takes one full render before onClickClickMe reactivates. It doesn't make sense that the click will wait for the re-render before calling onClickClickMe.

Comment: @someuser2491 Try commenting out the `Dialog's useEffect` and `onClickClickMe's if statement` to see if the button is properly closing the dialog when clicked.

Comment: okay i have used the ref for the button as i edited in my question and modified the onclick for button to what you mentioned earlier like this and it works now () => setIsDialogOpen((open) => !open)

Comment: @someuser2491 Isn't your buttonRef referencing your Dialog in your question's code? Oh well, if it works, awesome!

Comment: buttonRef will be referencing click me button and dialogRef will be referencing Dialog :)

Comment: @someuser2491 I updated the answer with my previous advice.

Answer (score -1):

Why not to just pass the isDialogOpen state to your Dialog and handle the toggle (show and hide of dialog) according to that? Something like:

```
function Parent() {
    const [isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen] = React.useState(false)
    const ToggleState = setIsDialogOpen(!isDialogOpen)
    return (
        <>
          <button onClick={ToggleState}>Click me</button>
          <Dialog isOpen={isDialogOpen} />
        </>
    );
}
```